# Changing the basis in codomain and domain of a linear transform and its effect on some result

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Question:
Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space and $T:V\rightarrow V$ a linear transformation. Let $B$ be a basis for $V$, and let $A$ be the matrix of $T$ with respect to $B$ (in both domain and codomain). Show that for any $v\in V$ and any scalar $\lambda$, the following are equivalent:
 - $v$ is an eigenvector of $T$ corresponding to $\lambda$;
 - $[v]_B$ is an eigenvector of $A$ corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda$.

I have **already proved** these two equivalences (mathematically, I don't understand them intuitively).

The next question says:
Does the same result still hold if we use different bases for $V$ in the domain and codomain? Explain.

I'm not sure how to mathematically prove if it does/doesn't hold. I would also like some intuition (or how you would intuitively describe this relation).

Answer (score 0):

No, it doesn't hold if the bases are different. Take any basis $B_1=\{{b_1,...,b_2}\}$ for your domain, and take $B_2=\{\frac{1}{2}b_1,...,\frac{1}{2}b_2\}$ for your codomain.

The matrix of $T=Id$ for this choice of basis is the matrix $A=2.Id$. Then $2$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, but not an eigenvalue of $T$.